# unable to start server , npm start gives error

Tags: react-native, watchman

I tried to start development server using npm start

all installation procedures were according to mentioned on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

I am getting error as following :

Looking for JS files in `/home/akash/appme`

Loading dependency graph...internal/fs/watchers.js:173
    throw error;
    ^

```
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/akash/appme/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/node_modules'
    at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:165:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1270:11)
    at NodeWatcher.watchdir (/home/akash/appme/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:159:22)
    at Walker.<anonymous> (/home/akash/appme/node_modules/sane/src/common.js:109:31)
    at Walker.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at /home/akash/appme/node_modules/walker/lib/walker.js:69:16
    at go$readdir$cb (/home/akash/appme/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:162:14)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:153:23) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/home/akash/appme/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/node_modules',
  filename: '/home/akash/appme/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/node_modules'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It’s hitting your system's file watchers limit

Try `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

Source : https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11406#issuecomment-458769756

Comment: thanks, thats work for me, and i documment it on my own blog https://rafibanget.blogspot.com/2019/11/how-to-fix-error-enospc-system-limit.html

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode try edit setting.json
File --> Preferences --> Settings --> OpenSettings

and exclude specific workspace directories, eg

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
"**/.git/objects/**": true,
"**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
"**/node_modules/*/**": true
```

}

source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc